# Converting a string to two ints?

Tags: c#, parsing, int, type-conversion

I have a string of the following form :

```
"(number) number"
```

So for example it may contain :

```
5 (5)
```

or

```
5 (3)
```

I wish to create an int variable which will hold the first value (in both cases 5), and a second int variable which will hold the value in the brackets (5 in the first case, 3 in the second).

What is the best way for me to parse this string and save the info in the variables as I wish?

Comment: Regular expression.

Comment: Did you mean "number (number)"?

Comment: The two examples are different from the pattern you presented (the value in parentheses is to the right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my $str = "(5) 3";
my ($x, $y) = $str =~ /\d+/g;
print "$x\t$y\n";
```

test link: http://ideone.com/PzidT

---

If you are not sure that input has exactly two numbers, then safer code is:

```
my $str = "(5) 3 4 (8)"; 
my ($x, $y) = ($str =~ /\d+/g)[0..1]; 
print "$x\t$y\n";
```

test link: http://ideone.com/dBIjh

Answer (score 0):

The fun way ;-)

```
var s = "5 (3)";
var space = s.IndexOf(' ');
var openParen = s.IndexOf('(')+1; 
var closeParen = s.IndexOf(')');
int firstNumber = int.Parse(s.Substring(0, space));
int secondNumber = int.Parse(s.Substring(openParen, closeParen-openParen));
```

Or the regex way:

```
var s = "5 (3)";
var match = Regex.Match(s, @"(\d+( \((\d+)\)");
int firstNumber = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
int secondNumber = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
```

Comment: Regex seems a bit of overkill, unless you have more uncertainty in the format of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
string input = "5 (3)";
string pattern = @"(\d+) \((\d+)\)";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
if (match.Success)
{
    int x = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
    int y = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
    ...
}
else
{
    // Fail
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a third option:

Take a look at the [String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) and the [Int32.Parse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head, so it might need some correction. You can split the string on all the characters you don't need, and have it remove any empty values.

```
string[] values = stringValues.Split(new char[] {' ','(',')'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string stringValue in values)
{
    int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(stringValue);
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some RegEx! `\d` specifies numeric values and `( )` specifies returned values..

```
var regex = new Regex("(\d+) \((\d+)\)");
var match = regex.Match(yourStringVariable);
```

So for `yourStringVariable = "5 (3)"`, the output would be:

```
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); // Prints 5
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value); // Prints 3
```